# atk4 simple dropdown from database table

Tags: forms, atk4

I want to populate a dropdown from a table 'accountgroups' which has 2 columns id and name. The first row of dropdown should be blank or '--Select Account Group--' when first loaded. Once the user selects the item (i.e. display field 'name' and value field 'id') I want to get id and name values when form is submited.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a model for your table first:

```
class Model_AccountGroups extends Model_Table {
    public $table='accountgroups';
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('name');
    }
}

$form->addField('dropdown','account_id')->setModel('AccountGroups');

if($form->isSubmitted()){
    $form->js()->univ()->alert('Selected ID='.$form->get('account_id'))->execute();
}
```

Comment: Hi Roman, I have already done like above code, it only gives me 'account_id'. I also need to know the selected 'name'. Apart from this, first item in the drop down should be 'blank' or '--Select Group--', so that user does not ignore the first item in the group and mistakenly submit the form without noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably (your post have an year and a half) you had resolved your issue, but I want anyway contribute with "my 2 cents" for this issue. I looked around (documentation, forums, etc) and neither found another solution to the same problem. My solution (tested and working) is this (please is is not efficient enough let me know):

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ON MODEL
class Model_Offices extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='Offices';
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('ID')->ReadOnly(True);
        $this->addField('OfficeName');
    }

    function GetAll() {
        $r=array();
        $AllOffices = $this->SetModel('Offices');
        foreach($AllOffices as $OneOffice) {
            $r[$OneOffice['ID']]=$OneOffice['OfficeName'];
        }
        return $r;
    }
}

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ON PAGE

        $m=$this->Add('Model_Offices');
        $form->addField('dropdown','Office')->SetValueList($m->GetAll()) ;
```

Mack